# Revit Addin getting information from model

Tags: c#, revit-api

I need a code that when I click on my Revit add-in button returns me the family of the model element that is selected. Anyone can help with this?

I did some research in Autodesk University and I couldn't find something easy to understand that make something near of this

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
var selElementId = uidoc.Selection.GetElementIds().FirstOrDefault();
var selElement = doc.GetElement(selElement);
var elemType = doc.GetElement(selElement.GetTypeId()) as ElementType;
var famName = elemType.FamilyName;

var fam = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
    .OfClass(typeof(Family))
    .Where(f => f.Name == famName)
    .FirstOrDefault() as Family;
```

there might be better solutions, but this should also do the trick

Comment: what type are those vars... uidoc and doc?

Comment: UIDocument and Document

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is other now. I'll ask another question. It's about getting/setting a value from a parameter into selected family